# .wav to any compressed form from AVAssetWritter ios

Tags: iphone, ios, avassetwriter

Well the problem I am facing right now is a size issue problem. I am allowing the user to to choose a song from their library and then chop it up into pieces and then be able to use the .wav or .mp3 file on their computer with file sharing enabled. Basically I am using the following AVAssetWritter options and I keep getting a giant huge audio file. E.G. 5 minutes of music is about 50MB. I am looking to try and cut that down to an industry given standard size. I have a feeling it has to do with the fact I am using LinearPCM as one of my options but when I change that or any of the Audio Options the writer can not write. I am also changing the FileType parameter on the AVAssetWritter. Here is my code which works completely fine I just need to find away to compress or shrink the files.

```
AVAssetWriter *assetWriter = [[AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:exportURL
                                                       fileType:AVFileTypeWAVE
                                                          error:&assetError]



NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM], AVFormatIDKey, 
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:41000.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [NSData dataWithBytes:&channelLayout length:sizeof(AudioChannelLayout)], AVChannelLayoutKey,

                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved,
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
                                nil];
AVAssetWriterInput *assetWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
                                                                           outputSettings:outputSettings]
                                        retain];
```

Any help on compressing or using my AVAssetWritter to write to different codec instead of WAVE or CoreAudioFormat would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: If there is a way to go straight from the music library to .m4a instead of .wav this would be the ideal approach I would like to take!

Thanks,
Nick

**ANSWER**

This is the correct audio options for .m4a and if you want the user to see it as an .mp3 or .wav file just append those onto the end of the file name!

```
AudioChannelLayout channelLayout;
memset(&channelLayout, 0, sizeof(AudioChannelLayout));
channelLayout.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo;
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:128000], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                [NSData dataWithBytes:&channelLayout length:sizeof(AudioChannelLayout)], AVChannelLayoutKey,                  

                                nil];
```

Comment: Try it with a more common sample rate (44100hz) instead of the 41000hz you are using. Then select file-type AVFileTypeAppleM4A and let us know how that worked.

Comment: @Till that didn't work now my AssetWritter can't add input. I think there is some incompatibility between the LinearPCM format and .m4a extension.

Comment: Ow, certainly - you also need to select kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC for the output settings.

Comment: Ok, cool now when I do that it crashes saying all the AVLinearPCM keys are not welcomed, which makes sense. Do you know what keys to use when using  kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC?

Comment: You should actually post your answer in the answer section and accept it when possible to adhere to the StackOverflow rules.

Comment: Will do. Just said I have to wait 8 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANSWER

This is the correct audio options for .m4a and if you want the user to see it as an .mp3 or .wav file just append those onto the end of the file name!

```
AudioChannelLayout channelLayout;
memset(&channelLayout, 0, sizeof(AudioChannelLayout));
channelLayout.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo;
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                            [NSNumber numberWithInt:128000], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                            [NSData dataWithBytes:&channelLayout    length:sizeof(AudioChannelLayout)], AVChannelLayoutKey,                  

                            nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this (sorry for not trying it myself but it should get you closer):

```
AVAssetWriter *assetWriter = [AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:exportURL
                                                       fileType:AVFileTypeAppleM4A
                                                          error:&assetError];

NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
       [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,
       [NSNumber numberWithInt:2], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
       [NSNumber numberWithInt:128000], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
       [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
       [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityHigh],  AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
       nil];
```

Comment: Hey man thanks it got me closer and I just figured it out! I'll post the answer soon.