# AVAssetWriter fails when audio Compression Settings are set

Tags: ios, compression, avassetwriter, avasset

When I have audioCompressionSettings as nil in the following code,

```
AVAssetWriterInput* audioWriterInput =
[AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
outputSettings:nil
sourceFormatHint:(__bridge CMAudioFormatDescriptionRef)[[audioTrack formatDescriptions] objectAtIndex:0]];
```

everything works fine.

If I add outputSettings:audioCompressionSettings, my Video comes out as a 0-byte file in iOS 7, 8, 9.
And in iOS 6, the following statement throws an error,

```
NSParameterAssert([mediaWriter canAddInput:audioWriterInput]);
```

My audioCompressionSettings is defined as follows,

```
AudioChannelLayout stereoChannelLayout = {
    .mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo,
    .mChannelBitmap = 0,
    .mNumberChannelDescriptions = 0
};

NSData *channelLayoutAsData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&stereoChannelLayout length:offsetof(AudioChannelLayout, mChannelDescriptions)];

NSDictionary *audioCompressionSettings = @{
    AVFormatIDKey         : [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC],
    AVEncoderBitRateKey   : [NSNumber numberWithInteger:128000],
    AVSampleRateKey       : [NSNumber numberWithInteger:44100],
    AVChannelLayoutKey    : channelLayoutAsData,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:2]
};
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

With audioCompressionSettings nil, iOS 6 spits out this error:

```
*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:
request:frame:decisionListener: delegate:
<NSInternalInconsistencyException> Invalid parameter not satisfying:
[mediaWriter canAddInput:audioWriterInput]
```

mediaWriter is defined as follows,

```
AVAssetWriter *mediaWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:outputURL fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4 error:&error];
mediaWriter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
NSParameterAssert(mediaWriter);
```

I actually want the iOS 6 issue to be fixed as I really do not want to do any transformation of the audio but just have it pass through.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152075/wav-to-any-compressed-form-from-avassetwritter-ios

Comment: Check out the answer in that link.

Comment: @st - Thanks for that link. But, no joy! This is a video file, whose audio compression is resulting in a failure.

Comment: Well probably it's like something you're simply missing, or it is a bug which I don't think so. Can you share the whole function ?

Comment: @st. Thanks for offering to help me.
The basic question I want answered is, when I set up audioWriterInput as described above, and do a NSParameterAssert on mediaWriter, why am I getting the error (as provided above)?

I have now updated my question above with my definition of the mediaWriter.

Comment: @Nat .. did you manage to solve this? @st.  I think we must not pass nil to the `outputSetting` of `AVAssetWriterInput `, even if we want to keep the audio as is i.e uncompressed.

Comment: @Nil - Sorry for my very delayed reply. You are correct that nil is not an accepted value. I solved it by catching nil value.